# Is cross-site lookup possible with a provider-hosted app?

Tags: lookup-column, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-hosted-app, cross-site

I have following problem. I got two projects, one sharepoint-hosted app and another provider hosted app. Both contain a couple of lists. So far so good.

Now I need the data from the sharepoint-hosted app in my provider-hosted app.

This diagram explains what I need to do:

[image]

I have been searching and so far have found nothing. I don't even know if this is possible, even in farm solutions I could only achieve this with moderate effort. I hope someone can shed a little light.

Comment: Are both Provider-Hosted and SharePoint-Hosted app's AppWebs in the same Site Collection?

Comment: as a precaution, I would say no. (really depends on the client)

Comment: There's no easy way to access SP-hosted app's AppWeb from outside app itself.
That's a lot easier and more maintainable to keep shared lists on HostWeb.
The other way is to implement custom WCF service (farm solution) and try to reach SP-hosted AppWeb by enumerating HostWeb's child SPWeb objects and checking SPWeb.IsAppWeb property.
But it would be neither fast nor reliable, imho.